# Downgrade python version

Tags: python, linux, centos7

I installed the latest version of python (2.7.14) but I overwritten the version that comes with my centos 7 (2.7.5), I would like to go back to this version (2.7.5) and install the latest version of python (2.7. 14) with altinstall to be able to have both.

Comment: perhaps off topic, but the latest version of Python is 3.6.3 at this time

Answer (score -1):

Follow [these](https://software.rc.fas.harvard.edu/training/scraping/install/source.html) steps for the version you want. For Python 2.7.5 use the `install` command and for python 2.7.14 use `altinstall`.

Comment: The problem is that i already install the python 2.7.14 version, i want to go back to 2.7.5.